# Routing does not work in Django: page not found (GET)

Tags: django

I've tried multiple methods of writing views but I don't think it is a problem here. App is installed in settings.py
It displays error every time.

project structure:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5PS3.png)

views.py (app folder)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

url.py in apps folder

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home_view/', views.home_view)
]
```

apps.py in app folder

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'app'
```

urls.py in store folder

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('app/home_view/', include('app.url')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

error message:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXIMo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a django web development expert I saw some small corrections to be done:

In store **urls.py** file its `app/` and `app.urls`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('app/', include('app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Then change the `app` **url.py** file name to standard name **urls.py**.

also don't forget to add your `app` to `installed_apps` variable in **settings.py** file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS=[
    'app',
    'django.contin.auth',
    #and other already specified apps
]
```

Rest all files have no bugs!!

According to this the correct path for `HttpResponse` is:

http://localhost:8000/app/home_view/

**OR**

http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/home_view/

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py file

Change

```
path('app/home_view/', include('app.url')),
```

To

```
path('', include('app.url')),
```

Then

On your browser go to:
127.0.0.1:8000/home_view/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The main thing it must be `app.urls` not `app.url`. change your file to `url.py` to `urls.py`, its recommended.

If you have defined `path('app/home_view/', include('app.urls'))` in `urls.py` of your `store` folder, then it goes to your `urls.py` which is in app.

In your `app's` `urls.py` you have written `path('home_view/',views.home_view)`.

It means if you type `127.0.0.1:8000/app/home_view/home_view/` then it will render your `HttpResponse` that is Hello world.